Blazor Server (.NET 8) Multiple Layouts (CSS/JS)
As I understand it, the new Blazor (.NET 8) web project uses App.razor component with the HTML markup and is the root component that is loaded first during app load.
The Routes.razor component then sets up routing and defines a default layout to be used for all page requests.
It's then assumed that common/repetitive HTML (like copyrights, menus, headers, footers, etc.) will be a component and added to a Layout file (like MainLayout.razor).
Generally, this works great (for Hello World), but if I wanted a layout that is used for 98% of my app with stylesheets and js files included (with some common functions that are executed that are related to the main layout) and then have another page component like a report or a login where I don't want ANY styling or any javascript executing.  How is this accomplished if the html and head is located on App.razor?

You can create multiple different layouts and apply them to different features. You can specify which layout a page uses with the @layout directive.

layout, yes, but not App.razor (where CSS and JS files are registered).  how is that done?

Have you considered using the HeadOutlet in the different layouts - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/control-head-content?view=aspnetcore-8.0.

Is there any difference between including js files in the head vs the end of the body tag?  There had to be a reason 12 years ago when that trend started, right?

I think it depends if you have a loader in the script file.
